# Образование деепричастия от глагола "запивать"

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите, будьте добры, можно ли образовать от глагола "запивать" деепричастие "запив"?

Answer (score 1):

> подскажите, будьте добры, можно ли образовать от глагола "запивать"
>   деепричастие "запив"?

Нет. **"Запивать"** - глагол несовершенного вида, соответственно от него и деепричастие будет несовершенного вида - **запивая**.

**Запив** - деепричастие от глагола "**запить**".

(+)
Словесных уродцев типа "запивав" (деепричастие со вторичным имперфектирующим суффиксом -ыва/-ева) настоятельно рекомендуется избегать, их предназначение - передать многократность действия, но в русском языке это избыточно.

Comment: "имперфектирующим" — как бы жили русские языковеды без немецких словечек, даже страшно представить...

Answer (score 0):

Деепричастие "**запив**" образовано от глагола "**запить**".

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/запив](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B2)

Деепричастие от несовершенного глагола "**запивать**" - "**запивав**". Но это очень редкое слово.

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/запивав](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2)

Например:

*Он ел печенье, запивав его чаем.* || Но можно по-другому переформулировать, чтобы лучше звучало.